# What's the preferred way to section a dynamodb table by client?

Tags: aws

Working on an application that uses DynamoDB for data storage, which is new-ish for me. There are two tables, both use a simple guid for their key. I need to divide data per client. Someone can sign up for their organisation, which means I need to separate data between clients. I was thinking of using a range key for clients, like

```
[id]            [client]
guid1234        org1
guid2345        org2
guid3456        org2
guid4567        org2
```

.. which means that I can use the current user ID to fetch their organisation and limit by range key. Is this the way to go? What's common here?

Comment: If you're uniquely identifying the Client, why do you need to rely on any key ranges? Seems like too much trouble.

Comment: @JeffO the client is not unique. It’s like an email in an account. The email is unique, the account is not

Comment: Org1 and Org2, etc. are unique aren't they and every client belongs to one of those?